# Force remote keyboard layout on Citrix Receiver

Tags: remote-desktop, keyboard-layout, citrix-receiver

I use Citrix Receiver to connect to remote applications from a Windows machine. The Windows machine uses a custom keyboard layout (derived from a non-English layout) which is not available on the server. This causes the server to fall back to the US layout, which is a poor match—I would prefer the non-English layout from which the custom one is derived.

I had once found a registry setting that enforces this kind of mapping in Citrix Receiver (something of the type “when the local layout ID is `a0000407`, use `00000407` instead” or “always use `00000407`, regardless of client settings”), but I can no longer find it.´

Note: access is through a NetScaler gateway and web portal, not sure if local APPSRV.INI settings take effect in that scenario.

Where can I make this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a Citrix solution but a workaround that does the trick for me:

- Open regedit and go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts`.
- Navigate to the subfolder for your custom layout and copy the `Layout File` value.
- Navigate to the subfolder of the system layout you would like to use and paste the `Layout File` value there, overwriting the existing one. (Make a backup if you’re unsure.)
- In Control Panel, switch to the default layout.
- Be sure to log out of all your Citrix sessions (local keyboard layout changes do not seem to take any effect whatsoever when you reconnect to an existing session).
- Reboot (may not be needed, though).

Side effect: anyone else on the same machine who has been using the standard layout so far will now effectively use the custom layout.